# Axiomatic set theory proof involving powersets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From Jech & Hrbacek, "Introduction to Set Theory":

Show that $\mathscr P(X) \subseteq X$ is false for any $X$. In particular, $\mathscr P(X) \ne X$ for any $X$. This proves again that a "set of all sets" does not exist. [Hint: let $Y = \{u\in X\,|\, u\notin u\}. \,Y\in \mathscr P(X)$ but $Y\notin X$.]

Obviously, if we can show that $\mathscr P(X) \nsubseteq X$ for any $X$, then it easily follows that $\mathscr P(X) \ne X$ for any $X$. I understand the structure of the proof of the former: Let $X$ be an arbitrary set. Then by the axiom schema of comprehension, the set $Y = \{u\in X\, |\, u\notin u\}\,$ exists. Assume (to the contrary) that $\mathscr P(X) \subseteq X$. Note that by the way $Y$ is constructed, if $z\in Y$, then necessarily $z\in X$. Thus, $Y\subseteq X$, which means, by definition, $Y\in \mathscr P(X)$. Hence, by hypothesis, it follows that $Y\in X$...

I cant seem to find a direct way to show that the last statement leads to a contradiction, which is what is needed to complete the proof. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $Y \in X$. Then by the definition of $Y$, the condition $Y \in Y$ would hold iff $Y \not \in Y$.

Comment: But what does $Y\in Y$ have to do with $Y\in X$?

Comment: The definition of $Y$ says that for any $u$, the condition $u \in Y$ means "$u \in X$ and $u \not \in u$." Apply this to $u = Y$.

Comment: You're correct, I understand that nature of Russel's paradox. Perhaps I'm not making the connection, but aren't we interested in deducing a contradiction from $Y\in X$? This is where I left off in the proof.

Comment: Applying this to $u = Y$, we have $Y \in Y$ iff ($Y \in X$ and $Y \not\in Y$). Except that here we are assuming $Y \in X$. So $Y \in Y$ iff $Y \not \in Y$. That is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, I believe I understand now. So we have deduced that $Y\in X$. Now, either $Y\in Y$ or $Y\notin Y$. If $Y\in Y$, then this leads to a contradiction by the definition of $Y$. On the other hand, if $Y\notin Y$, then an analogous (contradictory) conclusion is reached. Hence, $\mathscr P(X)\nsubseteq X$. Is this the gist?

Comment: Yes, that's it. But I think it's nicer the way they do it in the hint. They argue directly and identify a set $Y$ which belongs to $P(X)$ but not to $X$. You argue by the absurd. Therefore, though you establish that $P(X) \subseteq X$ cannot be true, you don't prove that the set $Y$ has that property (in real life, where $P(X) \not \subseteq X$).

Comment: I might argue your point. The two styles of proof should be logically equivalent. Showing that there exists some set (which turns out to be $Y$) that is an element of $\mathscr P(X)$ which is not an element of $X$ is equivalent to showing that it is not true that $\mathscr P(X) \subseteq X$, $Y$ serving as the counterexample leading to the contradiction. No?

Comment: The difference is that in your argument, you know that there exists $Y \in P(X) - X$, whereas theargument in the hint proves that and also identifies what a possible choice of $Y$ is.

Comment: Let me clarify. You write the absurd assumption $P(X) \subseteq X$ as part of your argument to show that $Y \not \in X$. Therefore, once your proof is finished, even though you know $P(X) \not \subseteq X$, you haven't actually proved that $Y \not \in X$. It's more elegant to prove that $Y \not \in X$ without using the assumption $P(X) \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 0):

We can construct $Y \in \mathscr{P}(X)$ as stated. The hint then suggests you prove $Y \notin X$, so the inclusion is *directly* falsified.

If $Y \in X$ then it is a possible element of $Y$ and testing the condition is then saying $Y \in Y \iff Y \notin Y$. So $Y$ *cannot* be an element of $X$, or the comprehension axiom would fail for $X$ and the predicate $x \notin x$. It's almost, but not quite, Russell's paradox, used for "good".

Later, we will choose to adopt the Axiom of Regularity and this implies $X \notin X$ for any set $X$, so then we also have an easy element of $\mathscr{P}(X)$ that is not in $X$, so $\mathscr{P}(X) \nsubseteq X$. The Russell trick is independent of regularity.

Comment: Do you concur with the previous reply that my original proof by contradiction doesn’t explicitly exhibit that the set $Y$ is a specific one which forces the conclusion? I construct $Y$ as well, before making any assumptions to the contrary, and use it in reaching the contradiction. Thus, $Y$ is the specific set which forces the contradiction, which means the negation of the contrarily assumed premise must hold ( $\mathscr P(X) \nsubseteq X$). Hence, $Y$ is the particular set which is an element of $\mathscr P(X)$, but not $X$. Perhaps $Y$ is more implicit here, but aren’t the two equivalent?

Comment: @Cyrus There is only one place where we use a contradiction: to show that  $Y \notin X$. One we know that we have an explicit set $Y$ such that $Y \in \mathscr{P}(X)$ and $Y \notin X$, which *directly* (by counterexample) shows that $\lnot (\forall x \in \mathscr{P}(X): x \in X)$ or $\mathscr{P}(X) \nsubseteq X$.